# Concise description of feature regardless of input device

Tags: accessibility

I'm trying to find a concise way to tell the user that by activating this option he will be able to draw something with just one gesture: whether he is using a mouse or a touch device as primary input device. The sentence I came up with is the following: (on mouse over my button shows the following)

"Allows you to draw with 1 gesture by pressing, moving and releasing on the main input device"

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: One potential flaw, the people using touch devices can't mouseover the button anyway..

Comment: @DasBeasto Yeah i'm showing it in some other way in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence could be improved by replacing the "input device" bit. This is not **user's language** so try to use more familiar and less formal words, like "*try to gesture with your finger or move your mouse to draw*". Of course this is not the optimal sentence and it can be improved.

What else you can do is **detect users device**, whether it is mobile or desktop and change the text or image depending on that, so if the user is from a desktop device show him the text "move your mouse to draw" or similar.

Lastly, the best thing to do is to include a **visualization of the gestures**. Just make a .gif displaying how when you move your mouse of finger the interface lets you draw something.